# Does the EMH have a sense of smell?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-emh

The EMH clearly can hear and see. He doesn't have a sense of taste. Can he smell?

Comment: Why revert the nice new title

Comment: I think the original is better. I want to know if the EMH has a sense of smell. Asking if he smells has more than one meaning.

Comment: Yes, that was the point. A little joy/humour in life. The body unambiguously defines the question. Ah well. (Also, you mean "whether", not "if")

Comment: Nobody said your original title wasn't "fine", but it could have been _better_ and more funny for HNQ. Not sure you fully appreciate the reason for the edit. Just a bit of a shame is all. & you want to know whether the EMH has a sense of smell. It's not the case that you want to know <some unknown thing> if he does (and not if he doesn't) :)

Comment: As Data states, "better" is a highly subjective term.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - see [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7296/should-this-be-a-clickbait-site-or-should-we-stand-by-se-standards-of-question).

Comment: @Mithrandir: C'mon, the edited title was neither "clickbait" nor "misleading". But it doesn't matter - we moved on several hours ago.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, the Doctor is fully capable of olfactory detection.

In the episode [Future's End, Part II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Future's_End,_Part_II_(episode)), the Doctor smells a tree, as referenced in the linked article.

[image]

This is quite a sensible feature for a medical hologram to have, given that the capability exists.  Many diseases have notable scents, and it would be useful for an emergency medical hologram to be able to use every conventional method of differentiation during triage.

Comment: Some diseases also have distict tastes, and back before more sophisticated technology was developed, doctors frequently not only smelled, but also tasted, e.g. diabetes was diagnosed by tasting the patient's urine.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley as I recall, diabetes mellitus translates to "honey flavored urine"

Comment: *Pseudomonas* has an *extremely* distinct smell.

Comment: @DuaneDibbley that's certainly true, but I'm pretty sure that even in triage situations it isn't encouraged for Starfleet medical personnel to lick their patients.

Comment: @Jeff I'm sure there's at least one Federation species that uses its prehensile tongue for fine manipulation, so as long as it's done in a sanitary fashion Starfleet probably has provisions for it.

Comment: Although the [Memory Alpha page](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Future's_End,_Part_II_(episode)) for this episode clearly states that he was smelling the tree, I'm just not seeing it in the episode. He seems to be *looking around the tree* (at the car driving away), rather than sniffing it. His acting may have been a bit too subtle here.

Comment: @Jeff LOL. You're probably right. But there may be circumstances where obsolete or even unorthodox methods are needed, because no current technology is available. If I remember correctly, Dr Beverly Crusher (I could be mistaken about it being her, but it was definitely a Star Trek series) told one of her staff to splint someone's broken arm or leg, and she was accused of not practicing medicine.

Comment: @Broklynite With the risk of going too far OT, diabetes is derived from the Greek word for _passing through_, a reference to the excessive fluid intake and urination seen in patientes with untreated diabetes, and mellitus is the latin word for honey.

Comment: Isn't the thing about tasting urine an old medical hazing technique: in front of class, professor demonstrates by dipping finger in beaker of urine and tasting finger. Invites hapless volunteer student to do same. Then says to class "did you see his mistake? You dip this finger [holds up index finger], but you taste *this* finger [holds up middle finger]"